# WebRTC std::deque iterator exception when RTC_DCHECK_IS_ON

Tags: c++, webrtc, deque

Recently, since M83 and M84 releases of lib-WebRTC, I face a strange error when I run my host program in Windows x64 Debug configuration (RTC_DCHECK_IS_ON) on Visual Studio :

When a video channel is creating in WebRTC library I get an exception on

```
_Deque_const_iterator& operator++() {
        #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0
            const auto _Mycont = static_cast<const _Mydeque*>(this->_Getcont());
            _STL_VERIFY(_Mycont, "cannot increment value-initialized deque iterator");
here---->   _STL_VERIFY(this->_Myoff < _Mycont->_Myoff + _Mycont->_Mysize, "cannot increment deque iterator past end");**
        #endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0

        ++_Myoff;
        return *this;
}
```

Because _Myoff is NULL ...

This ++operator is called from rtc_base/thread.cc in WebRTC library here :

```
void ThreadManager::RegisterSendAndCheckForCycles(Thread* source,
                                              Thread* target) {
    CritScope cs(&crit_);
    std::deque<Thread*> all_targets({target});
        // We check the pre-existing who-sends-to-who graph for any path from target
        // to source. This loop is guaranteed to terminate because per the send graph
        // invariant, there are no cycles in the graph.
    for (auto it = all_targets.begin(); it != all_targets.end(); ++it) {
        const auto& targets = send_graph_[*it];
        all_targets.insert(all_targets.end(), targets.begin(), targets.end());
    }

    ...
```

It comes from the ++it from a std::deque< rtc::Thread* >

I don't really see what might be the problem, but it seems that the iterator has an issue.

[image: Visual Studio debug]

Perhaps I have a kind of mismatch of configurations between the compiled webrtc.lib and my project but there wasn't any problem with WebRTC M79 or M81 for exemple.
And, as WebRTC is really a huge project, I don't know where to start my investigations.

Any idea ?

Please note that I also reported this bug to WebRTC team : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is from the function RegisterSendAndCheckForCycles of rtc_base/thread.cc file

```
for (auto it = all_targets.begin(); it != all_targets.end(); ++it) {
    const auto& targets = send_graph_[*it];
    all_targets.insert(all_targets.end(), targets.begin(), targets.end());
}
```

When all_targets.insert is called, the "it" gets invalid because the memory allocation changed in all_targets, so the next ++it generate an assertion failure. Working with indexes solves the problem

Here's the fixed version:

```
void ThreadManager::RegisterSendAndCheckForCycles(Thread* source,Thread* target) {

    CritScope cs(&crit_);
    std::deque<Thread*> all_targets({target});
    // We check the pre-existing who-sends-to-who graph for any path from target
    // to source. This loop is guaranteed to terminate because per the send graph
    // invariant, there are no cycles in the graph.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < all_targets.size(); i++) {
        const auto& targets = send_graph_[all_targets[i]];
        all_targets.insert(all_targets.end(), targets.begin(), targets.end());
    }

    RTC_CHECK_EQ(absl::c_count(all_targets, source), 0)
        << " send loop between " << source->name() << " and " << target->name();

    // We may now insert source -> target without creating a cycle, since there
    // was no path from target to source per the prior CHECK.
    send_graph_[source].insert(target);
}
```

I will propose a patch directly to WebRTC team in a few days

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a continuation of the accepted answer...

If you follow Microsoft's tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/winrtc/getting-started), they have you use the M84 release (still as of posting this in May '22).  Then, they tell you to apply a pile of git patches they put together.  To run those, they have you first define an environmental variable called `WEBRTCM84_ROOT` which is the absolute path to the `webrtc\src` directory.  If you didn't do all that, simply execute this in a Command Prompt window (filling in YOUR actual path):

```
set WEBRTCM84_ROOT=C:\abs\path\to\webrtc\src
```

Now, create a git patch file somewhere, containing the following content.  I'll just assume you put in it on a path directly *adjacent* to the webrtc repo.

**ThreadManager.patch**

```
diff --git a/rtc_base/thread.cc b/rtc_base/thread.cc
index 0fb2e813e0..a8cb022fa9 100644
--- a/rtc_base/thread.cc
+++ b/rtc_base/thread.cc
@@ -168,8 +168,8 @@ void ThreadManager::RegisterSendAndCheckForCycles(Thread* source,
   // We check the pre-existing who-sends-to-who graph for any path from target
   // to source. This loop is guaranteed to terminate because per the send graph
   // invariant, there are no cycles in the graph.
-  for (auto it = all_targets.begin(); it != all_targets.end(); ++it) {
-    const auto& targets = send_graph_[*it];
+  for (size_t i = 0; i < all_targets.size(); i++) {
+    const auto& targets = send_graph_[all_targets[i]];
     all_targets.insert(all_targets.end(), targets.begin(), targets.end());
   }
   RTC_CHECK_EQ(absl::c_count(all_targets, source), 0)
```

Then, apply it, like so:

```
pushd "%WEBRTCM84_ROOT%"
git apply "..\..\ThreadManager.patch"
git commit -a -m "Applied ThreadManager patch."
popd
```

> Note: I'm still experiencing some *other* bad behaviors in debug mode, that aren't present in release, but SamT's solution got me beyond this particular issue.